# jquery use id to switch button's image

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jquery function.
click on div class='open', it will open another session and the button will change image.
i switch id for css

however i need to change button's image back when i click it again.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".content").hide();       
                $(".open1").click(function(){
                    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
                                $('#btn_01').attr('id','btn_01_on');
                });
        });

</script>

<style>
#btn_01{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_on.png') no-repeat;}
    #btn_01:hover{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_over.png') no-repeat;}
    #btn_01_on{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_over.png') no-repeat;}
</style)
```

Comment: Please post some HTML for this issue or just fiddle it.

Comment: I do not believe you can effectively change and ID property on an element once is is in the DOM.  You should probably consider a class attribute instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching IDs is certainly not the best idea... You should use an `on` class to modify the display.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".content").hide();       
            $(".open1").click(function(){
                $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
                var btn = $('#btn_01'), isOn = btn.hasClass('on');
                if(isOn) btn.removeClass('on') else btn.addClass('on');
            });
    });

</script>

<style>

    #btn_01{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_on.png') no-repeat;}
    #btn_01:hover{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_over.png') no-repeat;}
    #btn_01.on{width:510px; height:109px; background:url('images/btn_01_over.png') no-repeat;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script snippet:

```
   var prevId = "btn_01";
   var nextId = "btn_01_on";
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content").hide();       
        $(".open1").click(function(){
            $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
            $(this).attr('id',function(index, id){
           return id==prevId?nextId:prevId;
        });
     });
  });
```

Now whenever you need to get back to the previous id, you can use prevId variable. This way your old images will start to show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".content").hide();
$(".open1").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    if ($(this).attr('id') == "btn_01") {
        $('#btn_01').attr('id', 'btn_01_on');
    } else {
        $('#btn_01_on').attr('id', 'btn_01');
    }
}
});
});
```